# Update table setting the value of a field to the result of a query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the following table(let's call it Sales) structure:

[image: Table Structure]

What I would like to do is to fill the field "SalesID" with values resulting from a query I have created in the same DB. This query reflects the table structure so I was thinking to connect the two using the ID.

Basically, I am trying with scripts of this forms:

```
UPDATE Sales 
SET SalesID = ( SELECT  SalesIDCalc FROM (SELECT Sales.ID, Sales.[Email Address], Sales.[Points], IIf([Points] >80,"Super","Normal") AS SalesIDCalc FROM Sales) AS q 
WHERE Sales.ID = q.ID);
```

but I am nowhere near the solution. Do you have any idea on how to proceed?

***EDIT***: Now I get the Error 'Operation must use an updateable table'

Comment: Please include the actual query.

Comment: ALTER TABLE is to modify table design, not UPDATE a field.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want `UPDATE` with a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE Sales
    SET SalesID = (SELECT SalesIDCalc
                   FROM (MyQuery) as q
                   WHERE Sales.ID = q.ID
                  );
```

Comment: Thank you, I've edited the question taking into account your suggestion and giving an example of MyQuery. Now, I get the error message 'Operation must use an updateable table'